# MongoDB MMS only monitoring "local" database

Tags: mongodb-mms

I have installed a MongoDB (2.6.5) instance and created a database with several collections.  After which, I installed and configured MMS (following Mongo's guide inside of the MMS site) and was able to successfully monitor the instance.  But it is ONLY monitoring the the database called 'local'.  When I log in to the mongo shell I can see the following:

> show dbs
>   TestV1  7.950GB
>   admin   0.078GB
>   local   0.078GB

But when i look in the dashboard for MMS I am only seeing stats for the local database.  Any idea how to get the other databases show show up?

Comment: Does the problem persists? And if yes – as dumb as it may sound – there is a dropdown box…

Comment: Yes it does persist and I found the drop down and the only db that is shown in that list is "local"  Thanks for responding though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all nodes in your replica set are running MongoDB 2.6.x, here are some likely possibilities:

1. DB Stats will not appear until ~30 minutes after a host is added to MMS Monitoring. If it has been longer than that, you should try refreshing the MMS page in your browser to make sure the latest configuration data has been loaded in the web UI.
2. Check that the "Collect Database Specific Statistics" option is Enabled on the "Administration => Group Settings" page in MMS. NOTE: this setting defaults to Enabled.
3. You have authentication enabled but did not configure [appropriate roles for the Monitoring Agent](https://docs.mms.mongodb.com/reference/required-access-monitoring-agent/).

For MongoDB 2.6 the monitoring agent requires:

- `clusterMonitor` role on the `admin` database

For more information, see:

- [How does MMS gather database statistics?](https://docs.mms.mongodb.com/faq/#how-does-mms-gather-database-statistics)
- [Required Access for Monitoring Agent](https://docs.mms.mongodb.com/reference/required-access-monitoring-agent/)